# Как изменить сообщение любого конкретного коммита?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Несмотря на большое количество этого вопроса в интернете, нормального решения я так и не нашел. В основном предлагают `git rebase -i`, но он как-то жестко перелопачивает все последующие коммиты, меняя их дату и порядок в списке, что плохо.
Нашел более-менее оптимальное решение:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = "$(git rev-parse --verify <коммит>)" ]
then
    echo develop1
else
    sed "s/.*/\0/g"
fi
' -- --all
```

`filter-branch` это пакетная команда, и она идет по всем коммитам, из-за чего приходится в передаваемом скрипте анализировать коммит и в случае неудачи вызывать `sed "s/.*/\0/g"`, иначе на все коммиты, кроме заданного, будут установлены пыстые сообщения. Есть ли возможность `filter-branch`-у задать конкретный коммит, или короче этой записи уже ничего не сделать? Возможно, есть другие способы изменения сообщения?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/2790048

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите изменить историю (поправить сообщение), не влияя на всю последующую историю (не трогая остальные коммиты). Это в общем-то противоречит идеологии гита.

Самый честный способ - `git rebase -i`.

Comment: сообщение коммита никак и не должно влиять на последующую историю, хотя filter-branch может менять почти что угодно

Comment: @Kosterio: sha-1 коммита все равно изменится после переименования. То есть это будет другой коммит со всем тем же самым, кроме текста сообщения.

Comment: @Kosterio: а поскольку ссылка на parent является частью любого коммита, то придется изменить и всю ветку коммитов, идущую от этого. Коммит - это immutable object.